# Syntax error converting datetime from character string when using Java Date Picker

Tags: php, sql-server

I am trying to do a query into a database to return a report with php. I am using duplicate pages as they both are pulling from the same database/tables.

The specific error I receive is:

Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Syntax error converting datetime from character string.

This query works and returns the desired data:

**REMOVED SELECT STATEMENT PER COMPANY POLICY**

This query however, does not work:

**REMOVED SELECT STATEMENT PER COMPANY POLICY**

I changed the DateUpdated to DateAdded in the cast portion. The Date/Time are obtained from a Java date picker script. Everything on the two pages are exact, except for the sql query. Does anyone have any idea what could be the problem? I am fairly new to PHP and so I am learning as I go.

I have tried searching but I do not understand what I should do.

I have these declared from the picker....

```
$startunix     = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($startdate));
$startunixmn   = date("Y-m-d 23:59:59", strtotime($startdate));
$endunix       = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($enddate));
$endunixmn     = date("Y-m-d 23:59:59", strtotime($enddate));
```

and within the sql query, in place of the dates/times that are showing in the statement, they have $startunix and $endunixm for the two dates/times. Are you not allowed to change what is in the cast? I thought you would be able to, because both columns are dates in the format 010109 (mmddyy). SO I figured if you change the DateUpdated to DateAdded (titles of the two columns) then the query should work, just based off of the date range selected for DateAdded instead of DateUpdated.

Any help or insight would be hugely appreciated. If you need more info, please ask and I will do my best to provide what I can.

Comment: You might have better luck if you limit the scope of your problem. It sounds like the root of your question lies in forming a proper query. If you ask a question about that, the answer will tell you how to write your php to get your datepicker to work. You should also specify/tag which database you're using so more people see it. Sounds like sqlserver.

Comment: Can you check if you have any strange values for DateAdded? It's likely that the problem is parsing one of those `(cast(LEFT(DateAdded, 2) + '/' + SUBSTRING(DateAdded, 3, 2) + '/20' + RIGHT(DateAdded, 2) AS datetime))` segments.

Comment: @Mike B : Yeah it is sqlserver (sorry about the tagging, my first time asking a question on here). I don't think there is anything wrong with the query, because it works with DateUpdated in the cast() portion of the statement, it just doesn't like being changed to DateAdded (different date column in the table).

Comment: @pajaja The data in the DateAdded column, are in the same format as DateUpdated which is 010109 (mdy).As far as I can tell, the dates/times being passed are the correct ones from the date picker. So I know there are no problems there. Both statements are exactly the same, except for the portion in the cast() where I change from DateUpdated to DateAdded (different columns in the table). I am not sure why it will not work with DateAdded instead of DateUpdated. When they are both in the same format.

Comment: @pajaja I did a select dateadded from cards order by dateadded desc and I found one entry that is NULL/Empty. Could that be what is causing my problem?

Comment: Yes it could since the db wont be able to make a string and parse it as datetime. Try to remove that entry and run the query again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case you will avoid the mentioned error by checking the if the `DateAdded` and `DateUpdated` are not null. Add the `DateAdded IS NOT NULL` in where clause.

It would be the best to insert once prepared value in database instead of parsing it every time you query the db. You said you are using:

```
$startunix     = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($startdate));
$startunixmn   = date("Y-m-d 23:59:59", strtotime($startdate));
$endunix       = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($enddate));
$endunixmn     = date("Y-m-d 23:59:59", strtotime($enddate));
```

but where does the string in `mmddYY` format then comes from? If you populate the `DateAdded` and `DateUpdated` fields with proper date ([check it here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/datetime.html)) you will be able to avoid making a new value from `DateAdded` field every time. Also if you don't need time, you can use `Y-m-d` format instead of `Y-m-d H:i:s` and will be able to shorten your query to something like this:

```
SELECT CardNo as CardNo, LastName as CLname, FirstName as CFname, Email as CEmail ,DateUpdated as CUpdated, DateAdded as CEntered FROM cards
WHERE recemail = 'YES' AND email IS NOT NULL AND email <> '' AND (DateAdded BETWEEN '2013-07-29' AND '2013-08-02') ORDER BY DateAdded desc, CardNo
```

Comment: Thank you for your help so far. The mmddYY data is how the database was set up (its where I work) and whoever set it up back in the day (early 2000's) set it up to put 010109 format as the date instead of a timestamp or anything like that. I manually Updated the NULL field in the one entry that was missing a date for DateAdded. And the query would still not run.

I am going to take a break from this page before I stab my eyes out haha. Would trying to post my code and having you look at the entire page, possibly help?